# aptana editor showing weird characters - indentation

Tags: javascript, html, aptana, indentation

my aptana studio started showing weird characters in the editor, im assuming its markup for code indentation. I think i activated it somehow while trying to find a comment keyboard shortcut... Any idea how to get rid of it? im on mac btw

rough example of what it shows, there are other characters showing that I dont know how to type on my keyboard (cant copy and paste it, it only shows it in the editor).

```
>>     >>
>>     >>
   Player.prototype.holderDiv;
   Player.prototype.innerDiv; 
>>     >>
>>     >>
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its showing up spaces for tabs
you should go in the preference and disable it
go to

```
Window > 
   Preference > 
        type text editors in top left box >
                  on right hand side uncheck show whitespaces  character >
                        Then say apply okay
```

Answer (score 0):

To toggle hidden characters in Aptana on and off, use the following keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>